# How would I take a string from an argument and use it in an if statement?

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I know how to do this in bash:

```
if [[ "$1" = "stringhere" ]]; then
    echo "Argument is equal to string!"
fi
```

How would I do this in Python?

Comment: Give it a try. But I doubt if SO users will just give you Python code.

Comment: It would be too easy wouldnt it @paisanco :)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv

Comment: If you need to grab arguments from the commandline, look into argparse module, not just sys.argv.  However, both answers are perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys.argv

if sys.argv[1] == "stringhere":
    print("Argument is equal to string!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following piece of code to get a basic idea:

```
import sys
print('Nr of arguments:'+ len(sys.argv))
print('Argument List:'+str(sys.argv))
```

The `sys.argv` variable holds all the arguments given and is accessible in the way that arrays are normally accessed in python.

You execute the program similarly to the bash-way: `python my program.py arg1 arg2`